# The simplest way to pass an image Id from a component to another one (image editor) in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass an image Id from a component (which is a tile list) to another component (which is an image editor). Both components are siblings.

**What is the simplest way?**

You can see both components code by following these links:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EOqlE1tYuU7fh8Ayme2IccYnqmQZrGBQ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yrAfsDnAXMY5oVZpxxU59ZTPCg67x2XT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a parent component which contains a state, which is passed down to both child components. When data changes in one component, it will update the state in the other, for example...

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const NavBar = ({yourState}) => <p>{yourState}</p>

const Login = ({yourState, setYourState}) => <button onClick={() => setYourState("world!")}></button>

const App = () => {
  const [yourState, setYourState] = useState('Hello')
  return (
    <div>
      <Login 
        yourState={yourState}
        setYourState={setYourState}
      />
      <NavBar 
        yourState={yourState}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I added the code. Do you mean I send the code to the parent component? or make the image editor child of the first component?

Comment: You would want to make one parent component with two children. So, you would initialise the state in the parent component and pass the state and the setState function to child A that sets the data, then the state to child B that displays the data. When you set the data in child A it will be passed to child B.

Comment: Can you please show by code in a simple example here or in other places?

Comment: Here's a sandbox with the example and some more notes: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-brook-9y9y5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: in your example each of them is functions, can I use this way in class components?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, just different syntax

Comment: Can you please convert the codesandbox.io to classes?